# Executar outro aplicativo (maps) no meu menu

Tags: android

Bom dia, sou novato no mundo android, gostaria de saber como faço para executar o aplicativo do google maps apenas apertando no meu botão?

Quero implementar minhas coordenadas e chegar no outro ponto cadastrado.

Comment: Você quer: 1) Iniciar o app (Activity) do **Google Maps** a partir do seu app, com uma determinada ação ou 2) Ter um mapa do **Google Maps** embutido no seu app? Como não ficou claro esses pontos, seguem dois links para ajudar: 1) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intents e 2) https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Comment: Iniciar meu app e no meu menu iniciar uma ação chamando o google maps fora do meu app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa chamar o Google Maps via `Intent`, assim:

```
private void callExternalMap(LatLng origem, LatLng destino) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + origem.latitude + "," + origem.longitude + "&daddr=" + destino.latitude + "," + destino.longitude));

        /*
        * Se você quiser que o usuário vá direto para o aplicativo do Google Maps, use a linha abaixo.
        * Caso não queira (de opções para o usuário abrir em outros aplicativos de mapas no celular), apenas apague a linha abaixo.
        */
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity"));

        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Verifique se o Google Maps está instalado em seu dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```